# Calculating the ratio of services to total jobs installed in one year.

Tags: statistics

I have had a total of 69 jobs this year, 13 of my jobs have had services this year. What is the ratio of services to total jobs?

Comment: @NobleMushtak The equation is not true. $\frac{13}{\color{red}{3}9}=\frac{\color{red}23}{69}=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Well, the ratio is simply $13:69$, as they have no common factors. A decimal approximation of $13\over69$ would be $0.1884$, to 4 significant figures, or $18.84\%$